# Linux intranet networking

Tags: linux, networking, routing

I want to set up a private network not connected to the Internet. I have a computer running Ubuntu Server 13.10 which I would like to function as a web server accessible from the other computers on the network, all of which are running Ubuntu Desktop 13.10. How should I go about setting up the networking? (I.e. `/etc/network/interfaces` on the server and the GUI config for the clients.) I need the computers to all be able to communicate.

I can deal with setting up static IP's (not using DHCP). All of the computers are connected with a switch.

Comment: Just to be clear, do you want a mix of computers connected to the same switch, some with access to the Internet and some only allowed access to the Intranet?

Comment: None of the computers will be connected to any external network; only the one switch and the computers connected to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The job is already done - with a normal setup you can already contact the other machines connected to the *same* switch by simply knowing their IP address. To find this, simply open a shell and type `ip addr`. This will show a listing with lots of information, of which the address to the current machine is four numbers separated by dots, typically starting with either `10.0` or `192.168`. To verify that you're able to connect to another machine, simply run `ping 192.168.x.y` (replacing the address with the real one) to check that it's reachable.

Once you've set up a web server on one of the machines, you can simply go to http://192.168.x.y to see the web site.

With regard to security, most home routers will be configured by default to *not* allow any connections originating from the Internet into your house. You should verify this in the router configuration.

Comment: It should be clear, that a home router with NAT is *not* offering any [security what-so-ever](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8772/how-important-is-nat-as-a-security-layer).

Comment: @MichaelP Yes, and the firewall that accompanies the NAT does. Your point?